# Disable Draw Mode in OneNote when using the pencil

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Is is possible to disable the "Draw mode" in OneNote?

I recently bought a Surface Go together with the Microsoft Pencil. I'm a heavy user of OneNote, but I don't need to make drawings the pencil. I just want to use the pencil in the same way as it behaves in other applications.

For example, I can use the pencil to scroll a web page up and down, left to right. In OneNote, I cannot do this, because, when it detects the finger, it automatically changes to the draw mode and instead of scrolling the page, it draws lines :(

I'm using the OneNote version pre-installed in Surface, which is a kind of RT version.

Comment: Do you have in File > Options > Advanced tab, under Pen, an option named "Use pen to select and interact with content by default" you can set?

Comment: No, I think this option is available only in the desktop version of OneNote. I have the stripped-down version of OneNote that comes preinstalled in Surface Go. I think the same one that you can install from the Windows Store.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution for this I found is to install the desktop version of OneNote (the one that comes with Office 2016).

In this version it is possible to change this behaviour in the advanced properties (Advanced -> Pen) and unchecking the option "Automatically switch between inking, selecting,..."

Comment: As of late 2020, this seems to be the only option and it works for me. Note that Microsoft supports both OneNote (Microsoft Office suite application with full MS Office option flexibility, such as disabling automatic inking) and OneNote for Windows 10 (simplified version on Windows 10 only that might be simpler, but lacks so advanced customization options). For details, see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-the-difference-between-the-onenote-versions-a624e692-b78b-4c09-b07f-46181958118f.